# KOhana Orm Factory Columns missing

Tags: orm, kohana-orm

I am facing weirdest of all weird problem right now. I have a table named events and it had 3 columns in it this morning. I added a new column named 'custom_url'. now when I do Orm::factory('event',$id); it shows only the old columns I even tried to change the name to abc ,still the column dosent show up in the out put .

Am i doing something wrong or are the list of columns defined in soem  file in Kohana ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have any cache available. Also try to change the name of one of old columns and check if they are updated.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your ORM code. Could be something like forgetting to add the column in your rules.

```
 protected $_rules = array(
    'custom_url' => array(
        'not_empty'  => NULL,

    ),
```

Kohana will only show the columns defined within your ORM. If you add new columns to the table it needs to also be included in the ORM code.

Comment: This is actually not true. Normally, the ORM automatically creates a property on the model for each column in the table so when you add a new column on the table, the model should have an identically named property.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post some code? Are you using as_array() to show the values as it may be skipping null properties? You can check if that's happening by using property_exists($event, 'custom_url').